# JRE_HOME environmental variable is not defined correctly bamboo error

Tags: bamboo

When i ran start-bamboo.bat file from windows command prompt. I faced the below errors even though JRE_HOME is defined.

> The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This
>   environment variable is needed to run this program

Comment: Did you try to see if JRE_HOME is set prior starting the .bat file? Maybe you should open an interactive prompt and set it first?

Comment: I was having this problem with JAVA_HOME, so I changed the path using ms-dos pattern ( c:\progra~1... ) and now I'm having the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your environment didn't have JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable set properly. You can check the validity of the path by typing in your command prompt

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%

echo %JRE_HOME%
```

If it is not set, follow the instructions mentioned in the Atlassian Documentation [Setting the JAVA_HOME Variable in Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) and run your `start-bamboo.bat` in the same command prompt.

Comment: That error doesn't mean that the variables are missing, I have both setup and still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, use the JAVA_HOME with shortened path but let the JRE_HOME with the full path:

`JAVA_HOME: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
 JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting just the JDK worked for me. You can try if other answers don't work for you.